# Perfect forwarding variable with unnamed type

Tags: c++

Are the following two versions always equivalent?

```cpp
for (auto&& elem : elems) {
  using E = decltype(elem);

  f(static_cast<E&&>(elem)); // 1
  f(std::forward<E>(elem)); // 2
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if `static_cast<E>(elem)` is also equivalent or not.

Comment: @MartinYork Because the intention is not to move, but to perfect-forward.

Comment: @MartinYork: They’re not always rvalues: `auto&&` is a forwarding reference.

Comment: @MartinYork: If it’s a container, we expect `auto` to be deduced as `X&` and so `E` is also that type.  If it’s a range of created objects (or xvalues), `auto` will be `X` and `E` will be `X&&`.

Comment: @DavisHerring Fair. I think that makes sense.

Comment: @Quentin Yes: https://godbolt.org/z/15Pxajfbq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, these are the same.

The rules for `auto&&` deduction mean that `E` is always a **reference** type here, so `E&&` is the same type as `E`.  That makes the `static_cast` “reassert” the **xvalue** status of `elem` if it has that.

It’s unusual to write `std::forward<T&&>` explicitly, but it works because that’s how `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` works in a **generic** lambda with `auto &&x` as a parameter (when the argument is not an lvalue).  So this also reasserts xvalue status, by design.